# query only returning partial data specified

Tags: php

I am trying to print the results of an inner join query based off of a POST variable from another page into a table. 
The page prints correctly when I use a simple query such as a "get etc. from etc. where id = $data. but when I use the inner join query nothing prints out on my following page, not even the table. 
I am assuming that something in the query must be causing it even though ran through phpmyadmin it works properly. 
Any suggestions?

```
     <?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    // connection
        $db=mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('MySQL connection problem: ' . mysql_error());
$mydb=mysql_select_db('mydb');


    $strSQL = "SELECT member_badges.bdgid, member_memberships.usid, member_memberships.msid, memberships.title
                FROM member_badges
                INNER JOIN member_memberships ON member_badges.usid = member_memberships.usid
                INNER JOIN memberships ON member_memberships.msid = memberships.msid
                WHERE bdgid = '$data'";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Badge ID</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Membership ID</th>
        <th>Membership Title</th>
        </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        echo"<tr">;
        echo"<td>" . $row['bdgid'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['usid'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['msid'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
     }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tested the query directly in the DB? Which DB are you using?

Comment: I have, just using the SQL input in phpmyadmin. It returns the results just fine.

Comment: Note that you should _strongly_ consider switching from the deprecated `mysql_*` functions to either [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Have you looked to see if `mysql_error()` contains anything?

Comment: Any chance that `bdgid` is a column in more than one table?

Comment: bdgid is only in my membership_badges table. However usid exists in 2 of the tables.